# Passing arguments to 'Run Shell Script' in Automator

Tags: terminal, automator, script

I want to make an Automator workflow to run a shell command. For example, I want to receive text input from the user and treat that input as a shell command instead of text. I have tried passing argument as `stdin` but still not able to make it work. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

The user input some text, say, 'xyz'. I want to pass this text to shell script as follow

```
echo "$1/"
```

to get `xyz` as the output of the shell script to show in *show result* action of Automator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When passing *input* to **Run Shell Script** in **Automator** you need to change **Pass input: to stdin** to **Pass input: as arguments** as shown in the example workflow below.

[image]